# SQL in Python: how to debug / print for an sql query with variables (%s)

Tags: python-3.7, mysql-connector

I'm using mysql.connector and Python 3.7.

For SQL queries, I use this method:

`cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (var1, var2, var3))`

The thing is... when I want to print or debug the entire sql query, I can't get the values instead of the %s (I know the whole point is that you can't).

How do you guys do to debug this, then?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't `print("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)" % (var1, var2, var3))` work?

Comment: I use string formatting and print it print("INSERT INTO table VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2})".format((var1, var2, var3))

Comment: @PaulS I'm gonna look into that. Thank you. Edit: that does work. However how could I get the query that is being sent through the cursor at doing cursor.execute?

Comment: @Y.S That's the method we were using before this, but heard its insecure?

Comment: @andopr if you just print it out to the console, and not passing the formatted string as a sql statement, i'm not sure security is a concern.

Comment: @Y.S sure, not in that case :D

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for printing [formatted strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) is the following:

```
name = "John"
print("Hello, %s!" % name)
```

You can apply that to your SQL statement and print it like this:

```
print("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)" % (var1, var2, var3))
```